# Delete duplicate entities with the same attribute values

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I am using Grakn. I'd like to delete a duplicate entity with the same attribute value (name). This is what I have now:

```
test> match $p isa person, has name $n; get;
{$p id V4176 isa person; $n "John" isa name;}
{$p id V40968336 isa person; $n "John" isa name;}
```

I would like to delete the one with id V4176. However if I do the query below, it deletes both entities:

```
match $p isa person, has name "John"; delete $p;
```

How do I just delete one of the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grakn assigns an auto-generated `id` to each instance. Although this `id` is generated by Grakn solely for internal use, it is indeed possible to find an instance with its Grakn `id`. To do so, we use the `id` keyword followed by the `id` assigned to the instance by Grakn.

```
match $p id V4176; delete $p;
```

Now, the reason your query

```
match $p isa person, has name "John"; delete $p;
```

deletes both entities is because both of them are `person` and `has name John`, so they both match you `match` clause.

You can find more information here https://dev.grakn.ai/docs/query/match-clause#one-particular-instance